# Magento category page products grid by sections with subcategories

Tags: category, products, category-products, product-grid, category-page

I need to create some specific layout for category pages in Magento.
The category page contains sections with product grids by subcategories for each of them

For more clarity here is a mockup of this:
[image: category grid with subcategories and products]

Is there any way to display products in a similar way. In sections for each subcategory. Perhaps there is a ready-made module for such output of products, or suggest some solution? Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Hello Edvin there could be a many different cases

**Case1 :** Category1 has child category LevelOneChild category, then LevelOneChild category has child Category LevelTwoChild category... How it should display products for LevelTwoChild category?

**Case 2 :** Category1 has two child categories CategoryA and CategoryB and same product is assigned to both the child categories, will same product appear twice under both the category section?

Comment: @TarunBhalodia thx for a comment! I think in this case, the main category has only first-level subcategories with products, 2nd level subcategories won't create. Also, each product is assigned only one subcategory, for a clearer structure. I hope it makes sense